# C# GMap.Net identifying position on a route

Tags: c#, google-maps, gmaps.js

My question is not so much code-oriented, it's more theoretical.

I'm currently working on an application for a sporting event. The goal is to be able to track competitors on a map while they are moving along a predetermined route.

Currently I have already been able to map the route and I'm able to place markers on the different locations using GMap.NET.

However I have two big challenges that I don't know how to tackle.

## 1 Calculating the distance and the (estimated) time until the competitors reach the finish.

So for every competitor that has a tracker with them, I would like to map him/her on the map and calculate the distance to the finish. In theory that should be easy. Every competitor will always be in between two waypoints and when I get the position of the tracker I could calculate the distance to the next waypoint and from there on I add every distance between the next waypoints and I have the total remaining distance to the finish.

But that's just theory, I have no clue how I could implement this.

Is there a way to know in between which two waypoints the competitor is?

And what should I do if, for example, there is a part of the route where the competitor goes up to a turningpoint at the end of the road and then comes back on the same road but just on the other side. How would I know if the runner is going up to the turningpoint or if he/she is on the way back from the turningpoint?

## 2 Working with loops inside the route

This is an even more complicated task. In the route there are two sections that the competitors have to do twice. They are large loops, not small ones. In order to get a correct calculation of the distance, I would need to find a way to know if the competitors are in the first loop or the second.

I was thinking I could probably use a quite similar approach as the issue above, i.e. to specify two waypoints in which I register the time that they have passed there.

If they pass again I could compare that time with the saved time and if there is enough time in between, I could conclude that they are in the second loop of that section.

But again, that's theory. The question is how would I do this in reality? And how do I calculate the distance properly? Do I specify two indexes of waypoints where I calculate the distance in between those indexes twice?

I would love to hear some of your insights on this.

Thanks,

Comment: 1: to calculate the distance, you cannot rely on the final geoloc of 1 user. you need an event of gmap, for each time it is triggered, Gmap notified the different geoloc of the user is changed, and then you can calculate the distance between his previous and current geoloc and sum it to the total of distance he walked. 2: by doing 1, you can get the distance they traveled, you just need to know the distance of the loop, and comparing the distance between two competitor (or even more), to know their position in a match

Comment: Thank you SKLTFZ, it was a bit hard to understand what you wanted to say but now I've got it. Essentially, when I receive a new position from the tracker, I have to create a route between the old point and the new point and get the distance from that route and save it in a log. This way I know the total distance he traveled and I can deduct that from the total distance of the route to know how far away he is from the destination. I think that's what you are saying right? In that case it doesn't matter indeed if there are loops in the route.

Comment: The only issue with that solution, @SKLTFZ is that when there are two possible routes between the old point and the new. Now in theory, chances of that happening are slim because I'm setting the update interval for the trackers to 5 seconds but still. But I guess I will just have to see what happens.

Comment: you just need to find the balance between performance and accuracy. accuracy is inversely proportional to the interval of geoloc update event